# Unable to connect to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried connecting to my firebase database, using the below configuration:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; 
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics"; 
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
export {app, db}
```

This is my submit code:

```js
onSubmit={(values) => {
  db.collection("messages").doc("user").set({
    fullName: values.fullName,
    companyName: values.companyName,
    email: values.email,
    description: values.description
  }).then(() => {
    toast("Message Sent Successfully")
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  })
}}
```

I got this error when I tried to submit:

```js
formik.esm.js:937 Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: _firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.db.collection is not a function
```

I am unable to connect to firestore

Comment: What version of firebase?

Comment: It says db.collection("messages") is not a function. use `console.dir(db)` to check what functions are available

Answer (score 1):

Following [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=pt-br#set_a_document) you should connect to your database using `addDoc` or `setDoc` functions.

As you said in your comment: `db.collection... is not a function`, so this should solve this error:

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(doc(db, "messages", "user"), {
    ... document data ....
  });
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

BUT.... as I saw in your question you're using `toast` wich I suppose to be a mobile function so in this case you should use `@react-native-firebase` to connect in your database. In this is the case `firestore().collection("messages").doc("user")....` is the correct syntax and you're only using wrong library. You can also read about this [here](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage).

Hope this helps you.